# Yet another... Password

Tags: riddle, password

Help me figure out my password, please. I need it to vote in the elections.

Here is the formula I used to create the password:

> Stacks and Stacks of culinary
>   2196's hometown
>   Tallest there
>   Fathers names (LastLast)
>   Rot 4ever
>   That is my password. Just add a smiley.

Comment: "Most famous" seems *very* subjective.

Comment: @Deusovi Yes. And famous when? Then or now?

Comment: I'm still stuck on the most famous man from there. Is there any particularity that distinguish him from the others?

Comment: @Thrax I apologize, my error. I changed the code slightly to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer, but maybe my thoughts could help someone figure out how to solve it..

Stacks and Stacks of culinary 2196's hometown

> refers to some SE

Most famous man from there

> user with the most reputation of that SE?
>  **UPDATE:** after reading the comment of **Thrax** the user 2196 is from Chicago, IL, therefore we might be looking for a famous person from there

Father's name

> depends on the users name

Rot 4ever

> some sort of rot cipher? maybe caesar shifted by 4, maybe rot13..

Don't know if this is helpful but might as well share it ;)

Comment: For the first clue, I went on "Cooking SE", looked for a user with "2196" in his name and found him : http://cooking.stackexchange.com/users/2196/user2196. This user seems to be from Chicago, IL.

Comment: User2196 has a badge for "famous question" could that tie into the hint "most famous man"?

Comment: @Thrax Good catch! Now just follow the clues to the most simple and logical conclusions.

Answer (score 0):

Stacks and Stacks of culinary 2196's hometown

> Chicago (user2196 hometown)

Tallest there

> Willis tower? (or: [Don Koehler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don_Koehler)?)

Father's name

> [Henry Willis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_Willis)? Alternatively the Willis tower parent company is 'Willis Towers Watson'. Or, a bit of a stretch but Willis tower was previously named Sears tower.

Rot 4ever

> This is where I get lost. You could say Sears is rotting. Or maybe the names Watson or Henry have other meanings related to this.

That is my password. Just add a smiley.

> Or maybe none of the above means anything and this is the answer.

My guess:

> That:)